# hijack program’s command to run notepad

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a utility programs’s EXE file, when i run this file there is a winform only and there is button when we click on it, it run windows’s notepad. Now I want to hijack this program’s command to run notepad and instead of running notepad I want to run MS Word. I know C# and VB.NET. What I need to do this ?

Comment: First thing you need to do is provide some code.

Comment: have a look at my answer. all downvote but no one seems to know how to do it better and i know it should work unless the app is protected at which point it would be to hard to explain how to do it and it would be a crack request

Comment: @Korin: no its not my program I have download it from internet.

Comment: @user673924: Then read the license. You're most likely not allowed to alter or temper with it.

Comment: @Bobby: no its not a commercial one.

Comment: @user673924: Commercial is not a License.

Comment: @Bobby: No there no such License with this exe.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to add in folder with this program your own program called notepad.exe that should do only one thing: run word.

If you want to do it programatically in C then you should read this page - maybe it helps: [Intercepted: Windows Hacking via DLL Redirection](http://www.ethicalhacker.net/content/view/207/2)

Comment: @Korin: my seniors told me that this can be done using system call interception, but I don't how?

Comment: 1+ . use this method. i delete my answer (not that i think im wrong, but this will work)

Comment: @user i doubt youll do an interception in .NET and if you will it will be an overkill :P you could inject a .dll to install a hook on create process but that also is an overkill

Comment: can we do it through C language?

Comment: If you want to do it in c then read this page - maybe it helps: http://www.ethicalhacker.net/content/view/207/2/

Comment: @Korin: I want to give a upvote for this attempt, but I can’t becuse my rep. points are less than 15. Any way this is a very good link.

Comment: yes, but I am looking for some more information in this regard.

Comment: This solution *might* work. It depends on if the program in question is specifically running notepad.exe, or using file name associations to determine which program to run.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: how can I find out this?

Comment: @jams: try this solution and see if it works. If this solution works, then it's probably not using file associations.  If it is using file associations, then you don't know which file association it's using (i.e. .txt, .log, .html, or whatever).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a trick to replace programs with another by making changes to the registry.  This will work even if the program you are running uses absolute paths to run notepad. It overrides any instance of the running program with the chosen one no matter where it resides. And you won't have to patch the file.  The key you'd be interested in is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
```

Add a key with the name of the program and add a `Debugger` string with the path to the program you want to replace it with.  Of course you need to have permissions to make the necessary modifications.  This [page](http://code.kliu.org/misc/notepad2/) explains how you can replace Windows Notepad with another program.  You can apply the same process here.

---

Though you'll probably not want to have this permanent change, so you can write up a program to temporarily add/change the key, run your program then change it back.  Here's a complete one I just whipped up to temporarily replace Notepad with Word for a demonstration.  Seems to work perfectly fine (though as always, use at your own risk).  Just make all the necessary changes to fit your situation.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ProgramLauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        // change the following constants as needed
        const string PROGRAM_NAME = @"notepad.exe";
        const string REPLACEMENT_PATH = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE";
        const string RUNNING_PATH = @"C:\Windows\notepad.exe";

        // root key
        const string KEY = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var rootKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(KEY, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
            {
                var oldPath = default(string);
                var needsRestoration = false;
                try
                {
                    oldPath = BackupKey(rootKey, PROGRAM_NAME, REPLACEMENT_PATH);
                    needsRestoration = true;
                    Process.Start(RUNNING_PATH).WaitForExit();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (needsRestoration)
                        RestoreKey(rootKey, PROGRAM_NAME, oldPath);
                }
            }
        }

        static string BackupKey(RegistryKey rootKey, string programName, string newPath)
        {
            Debug.Assert(rootKey != null);
            Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(programName));
            Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPath) && System.IO.File.Exists(newPath));
            if (newPath.Contains(" "))
                newPath = string.Format("\"{0}\"", newPath);

            using (var programKey = rootKey.CreateSubKey(programName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
            {
                var oldDebugger = programKey.GetValue("Debugger") as string;
                programKey.SetValue("Debugger", newPath, RegistryValueKind.String);
                return oldDebugger;
            }
        }

        static void RestoreKey(RegistryKey rootKey, string programName, string oldPath)
        {
            Debug.Assert(rootKey != null);
            Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(programName));

            if (oldPath != null)
            {
                using (var programKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(programName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
                    programKey.SetValue("Debugger", oldPath);
            }
            else
            {
                rootKey.DeleteSubKey(programName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```